# how to restart upgrade during middle of upgrade session

Tags: 12.04, apt, do-release-upgrade

I was upgrading from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04

sudo do-release-upgrade

after this downloaded 700 Mb of packages in approximately 10 hours and upgrade etc started 
I am finally stuck up here during the upgrade process
system has stopped with following message

```
Setting up ubuntu-wallpapers (0.34.1) ...
Setting up adium-theme-ubuntu (0.3.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up update-manager-core (1:0.156.14) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades ...
Setting up update-notifier-common (0.119ubuntu8.1) ...
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/arial32.exe
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/arialb32.exe
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/comic32.exe
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/courie32.exe
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/georgi32.exe
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/impact32.exe
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/times32.exe
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/trebuc32.exe
```

If you notice probably in the last line where it mentions

```
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/trebuc32.exe
```

this is where it has hanged it either is unable to retrive the file or some thing happened here is there a way to get past this and proceed with upgrade?

Comment: They seemed to have changed the folder path on the server, but didn't update the install code to reflect the change.
Installer is looking here for the files
http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/ The file are have been moved to here
http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/files/the fonts/final/